# Create variable names on demand

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a console minigame (for fun), and I need to create a map(graph) with a predefined number of rooms(vertices).

I'd like to define a `class room` and create instances of that class that will be assigned to variable names like `room_1`, `room_2` and so on.

My problem is, that I don't know how to create these variable names. To cut a long story short, I need a tool/tip/trick  to create preformated variable names on demand.

F.i let's say that `MAX_R=5`, then I'll need variables `room_1` to `room_5`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dict instead.

```
rooms = dict(('room_%d' % x, Room(x)) for x in range(1, 6))
```